# Custom UIView from outlet

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I know this has been discussed a number of times but I still have some problems getting around the problem, so any help would be appreciated. I have a class MyView which subclasses UIView. So far so good, in this custom class I basically configure the layout, UI, etc.

Now, I have a separate UIViewController and what I want to do is create an outlet for that custom view. In the view controller's Nib I set the view's class to that of my custom view and connect it to the outlet, but I can't see anything apart from a blank view.

How and where do I load the view from nib? Do I simply say self.theOutletForMyCustomView = load from nib or is it something else? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to set the name of your `CustomView` inside your `UIViewController` nib file like that 
[image: Xcode]

Then, you have to retain your property like that inside your `UIViewController interface` :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CustomView *myCustomView;
```

or an `ivar` should work, but `assign` an `IBOutlet property` doesn't work.

And if you customize your `CustomView` inside your `CustomView class implementation`. Beware of doing your initialization in `awakeFromNib` or `initWithCoder:` instead of `initWithFrame:`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, yes I've done it. However I get a blank view.

Comment: @MarioPen: Have you custom your CustomView inside your UIViewController nib file, or inside your CustomView implementation ? NSLog(@"%@", self.myCustomOutlet); What display this log ?

Comment: Yes, I've set both classes correctly, the log shows the outlet is indeed properly connected and pointing to my class. The thing is the view that I've dragged (and changed it's class) inside my view controller's view is blank and that's what it's showing. My custom view has some labels and images in it and none of those are showing, which leads me to believe that it's not loading from its NIB